# Replace bow saw blade: Blade affixed with permanent rivet?

Tags: hand-tools, saw

I need to replace the blade on a bow saw/bucksaw.

It looks to me like the existing blade is affixed with a rivet, not a removable pin or bolt.

[image]

[image]

New blade:

[image]

*(Both ends of the new blade look the same: two holes.)*

---

I just want to make sure I'm not having a brain fart.

Is the only way to replace the blade to **drill-out the rivet** and replace it with a bolt & nut? If so, that seems like a bad design.

I ask because I'm at cottage in a somewhat remote location, so it will be an ordeal to scrounge up a drill, the right size drill bit, and a bolt/nut. I want to make sure I’m doing it right before I go through the hassle of modifying the saw by adding a bolt.

---

*The brand name of the saw is Benchmark from Home Hardware: https://www.homehardware.ca/en/24-bow-saw/p/1062281?page=search-results%20page*

Comment: Seems a bad design.  Would imagine two hooks with one being adjustable to tighten the blade.  Might be a good time to learn to sharpen the blade.  Anything against chainsaws.

Comment: can you show us the other side?  Doesn't look like a rivet, but something that goes through the blade and catches the other side, and falls out if you loosen the blade.

In any event, rivet guns are cheap.

Comment: driving a nail into the cupped end should pull the metal in to the center and loosen the rivet. If not, keep using bigger nails until there's only a small ring of metal around the edge, at which point needle-node pliers should be able to make short work of it. replace with a short bolt, ziptie, cotter pin, etc.

Comment: I'm guessing that the manufacturer didn't feel most people would bother replacing the blade, vs just buying a new saw.  The difference in cost would be minimal.

Comment: drill, file, grind, or cut out the old rivet and replace with new rivet

Comment: That bow saw seems to be about as old as the ruler. Congrats on continuing to use the classics!

Comment: You don't need to drill out the rivet!  Release the blade tension, and you can pull out the rivet far enough to release the blade.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The silver part on the handle of the saw is pulled down and away from the frame. Then the tension on both of the pins is released and they can be removed and a new blade inserted. The pins are rusted and may take some WD-40 and coercing to be removed. This releases the blade. Reverse the process to install the new blade.

Comment: I guess the key point in the answer is that the "rivet" is actually a pin that should come out when the tension is released.

Comment: In my experience, the rivet is often captive.  But the hole in one side of the frame is larger than the other.  So with the tension released, you can push the rivet far enough through to release the blade, without losing it.  After inserting the new blade, push the rivet back through both sides of the frame before re-tensioning the blade.

Answer (score 1):

DON'T GIVE UP. Keep wiggling and turning the pin. It will come out. It is just as difficult to get it back in, but took less than a minute to get it out and less than a minute to put it back in.